# Is a factorable polynomial invertible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, inverse

The reason there exists no quintic formula that finds the roots of a quintic polynomial is simply because some quintic polynomials are irreducible.

But reducible quintic polynomials may be invertible in a case by case scenario:

$$f(x)=x^5-1$$

$$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[5]{x+1}$$

But are all reducible quintic polynomials invertible?  Proof please?

Comment: What do you mean in your first sentence? Are you confusing "reducible" with "insolvable"?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger No actually (I think).  If you can reduce a polynomial so that the problem is factoring a quartic or lower degree, then it is fully factorable.  I believe that's the same as solving it. (set equal to 0)

Comment: But how does the existence of reducible quintics imply the absence of a quintics formula? Did you mean "irreducible"?

Comment: Note, by the way, that not all irreducible quintics are insolvable. For example, $x^5-2$ is irreducible over the rationals, but its roots are clearly the fifth roots of $2$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, my bad.  I'm meant irreducible.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger All quintics irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ have insolvable roots in closed form.

Comment: No quintic is irreducible over $\Bbb C$, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I meant that the roots in $\mathbb{C}$ are not expressible in closed form.

Answer (score 1):

$$-x^5-x$$
is clearly reducible, as its equal to $-x(x^4+1)$. However, $f^{-1}$ is the [Bring radical](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical), which is not expressible in terms of regular radicals.

If you want a quintic without any inverses *at all*, not just a quintic whose inverse is not expressible by radicals, any quintic that's not injective (such as $x^5-x$) will do.

Answer (score 0):

I take it your "invertible" means that there is an expression in radicals $g(y)$ such that for all $y$ in some interval, $f(g(y)) = y$.  But if $f$ is any polynomial of degree $d > 1$, there is a set of $y$ dense in some interval such that $f(x) - y$ is reducible: namely take $y = f(r)$  for rational $r$, in which case $f(x) - f(r)$ is divisible by $x-r$.  Thus for any non-invertible $f$, $f(x) - f(r)$ for rational $r$ is a counterexample.